# Websphere Application Server - Oracle 11g DB compatibility issue

Tags: oracle11g, datasource, websphere-7

I have been given an ad hoc reporting tool from another individual that has successfully deployed it to the field.  He uses Web Logic servers and an Oracle database.

I tried to deploy the same application in my local environment (WAS 7 and Oracle).  The first report runs flawlessly.  However, when I run the second (or third or fourth) report, I get a very strange error: the second report is appended to the first report.

There is nothing in the code to account for this.  This problem can be temporarily solved by stopping and starting the servers every time a report is run (obviously not a real solution).  I think this has something to do with data sources and cached information.  I then took a step back and tried to deploy it to a Tomcat server.  It works perfectly, just like it does in the field.  So my question is: **are there any known issues between WAS 7 and Oracle 11g that could be causing this kind of problem?**  Any information would be very helpful.

Please ask about any specifics you may want to know and I will do my best to provide that information.

Thank you for your time.

EDIT:  For anyone else looking into this, the problem was due to an incompatibility with the proprietary Oracle calls and Websphere.  Once the application was edited to use only JDBC calls, everything works perfectly.  Thanks.

Comment: Seems like a Compatability problem of the application to WebSphere which might not have anything to do with Oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a incompatibility with using proprietary Oracle calls and Websphere.  It was fixed by changing all of proprietary call to normal JDBC calls.